# Find commands by name

Tags: interface

I started using Blender and I am wondering if you can search for the commands by name, similar to what code editors like Atom are offering. I couldn't find such an option yet.

[image: Atom example]

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use <kbd>F3</kbd>. This will list the commands, and even show you the shortcuts (if they exist)

The shortcut is <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> for older versions of blender (< 2.80).

[image]

Comment: Also note that this is contextual: Pressing space on the UV editor will show UV commands, this also depends on object/edit mode.

Comment: @Kroltan Good note. I nearly put that in, but I wanted to do it properly, since its slightly more complicated then that, and didn't have time to test 'cause I was in a hurry.