# I Want to Access Walk Mode in Texture Paint Mode With Shift + F

Tags: camera

Currently if i press shift + f in texture paint mode it gives me the brush strength scaler. It works fine in object and edit mode. What options do i have?

Comment: I think the shortcut is Shift-F....?

Comment: Yes it is. I edited my post. I got it confused. Thanks for your other answer. It worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the <kbd>Spacebar</kbd> menu > *Walk Naviation* (you have to use type search, [see more here](https://blender.stackexchange.com/a/40170/3127)) will do the trick. There is currently no shortcut for this in texture mode.

If you want to add or override a shortcut for it, we can do this in the user preferences, *File*>*User Preferences* or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>Alt</kbd>-<kbd>U</kbd>.

(*Note: Opening up a new instance of blender is a good idea if you don't want to mess up you startup file*)

Go into the input tab. Tab into 3D view and then into image paint. Next look for the shortcut you want to override, if it is not there, use add new.

[image]

Fill out the above form with the infromtaion, be sure to enter `view3d.navigate` into the little text box.